# How to determine if a column contains certain elements in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to check if the column `app` contains the element of `myList`.

```
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.DataFrame({'app':['a,b,c','e,f']})
myList=['b', 'f']
print(df)
```

`Output:`

```
     app
0  a,b,c
1    e,f
```

`Expected:`

```
     app  contains_b  contains_f
0  a,b,c          1           0
1    e,f          0           1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) for all indicator columns and then filter them by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by list:

```
df = df.join(df['app'].str.get_dummies(',').reindex(columns=myList).add_prefix('contains_'))
print (df)
     app  contains_b  contains_f
0  a,b,c           1           0
1    e,f           0           1
```

Or use loop with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and casting boolean mask to integers:

```
for c in myList:
    df[f'contains_{c}'] = df['app'].str.contains(c).astype(int)
print (df)
     app  contains_b  contains_f
0  a,b,c           1           0
1    e,f           0           1
```